# For every submission, first inserted row is duplicated

Tags: php, header

I'm creating a comment form. Each time I submit the form the first  added row is duplicated. I've tryed to resolve it with header and exit. But that wouldn't work either. Could someone please guide me?

```
<?php 
    $reizen = new reizen;

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        $reizen -> comment($username, $comment);
        header("Location: index.php?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
        exit();
    }
    echo $reizen -> retrieve();
    $output = '';
    $output .= '<html>';
    $output .= '<head>';
    $output .= '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css"/>';
    $output .= '</head>';
    $output .= '<body>';
    $output .= '<div id="contactform">';
    $output .= '<form name="form" id="form" action="index.php?page=review" method="post">';
    $output .= '<label>Name:</label>';
    $output .= '<input type="text" name="username" />';
    $output .= '<label>comment</label>';
    $output .= '<textarea name="comment" rows="20" cols="20"></textarea>';
    $output .= '<label><img src="captcha.php"></label>';
    $output .= '<input type="text" name="code">';
    $output .= '<input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Send message" />';
    $output .= '</form>';
    $output .= '</body>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '</html>';
    echo $output;
?>
```

public function comment($username, $comment)
{

```
if(!empty($username) && !empty($comment))
{
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    if($insert = $this->db -> prepare("INSERT INTO reviews (username, comment, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"))
    {
        $insert -> bind_param('sss', $username, $comment, $date);
        $insert -> execute();
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "iets gaat mis met inserten";
    }
}
else 
{
    echo "missing fields";
}
```

}

```
public function retrieve()
{

    if($retrieve = $this->db -> query("SELECT username, comment, time FROM reviews ORDER BY time LIMIT 5"))
    {
        while($row = $retrieve -> fetch_assoc())
        {
            $output .= '<div class="comment">';
            $output .= '<div class="name">'. $row['username'] .'</div>';
            $output .= '<div class="date">Added at '. date('H:i \o\n d M Y', strtotime($row['time'])) .'"></div>';
            $output .= '<p>'. $row['comment'] .'</p>';
            $output .= '</div>';
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        $output .= "iets gaat mis met retrieven";
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine... I'd say something else is at play. Maybe your page is getting loaded twice or something. Make sure you're not a victim of prefetching or something.

Comment: Could it maybe come due to the action within the form?

Comment: Maybe - where do you use the $_GET variable `page=review`?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this can be a problem:

```
$reizen->comment($username, $comment);
header("Location: index.php?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

$reizen->comment($username, $comment); sends an echo to your output buffer.
Your header won't be send... 
A header must be placed always BEFORE ANY output.

So try

```
header("Location: index.php?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$reizen->comment($username, $comment);
```

Comment: You might be onto something. Instead, what I would do is prevent `$reizen->comment` from sending anything to the screen first though. If your answer works, then he should rewrite his `comment` function.

Comment: I agree. I think he would use the 2 echo's for debugging but i think they are not necessary. And nice name Mr HansWorst ;)

Comment: Why this line: $insert -> bind_param('sss', $username, $comment, $date);